# Stored procedure with parameter database name?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

Is there anyone to call and run a stored procedure with the database name (they are snapshots, one created per client) as a variable passed to the stored proc?  The tables themselves are known and won't be variable.  I could put this stored proc on another central database and have it reach across to the variable one, I'm imagining.

Right now, it's executing dynamic SQL in C#/ASP.NET by taking a text file with the DB script and replacing text variables inside of it.  I'd like to try doing as a stored procedure instead.

Comment: You can do it as a stored procedure that uses dynamic SQL(or possibly even the variable EXECUTE command).  Give us an example of what you want to do, so that we have enough details to make a meaningful example.

Comment: It's not an option to have this Stored Procedure in each database, and depending on your parameter just connect to the proper database, then call the Stored Procedure?

Answer (score 3):

If you pass a database name (or any other object name) to a stored procedure, you only have two ways of handling it in the stored procedure:

1. Dynamic SQL
2. IF-based handling:

> ```
> IF @DataBaseName = 'A'
>   EXECUTE A.dbo.StoredProc
> ELSE IF @DataBaseName = 'B'
>   EXECUTE B.dbo.StoredProc
> ELSE IF 
> ...
> ```